# Downloading an image through <a download> where href contains a php variable which holds the content of the image

Tags: php, html

Here's the snippet of my code where $arr[$i]['notes'] stores the content of the image retrieved from the database

```
<div class="subs">


        <?php
            echo '<table style="width:100%">';
            echo '<th>Subject Code</th>';
            echo '<th>Subject Title</th>';
            echo '<th>Semester</th>';
            echo '<th>Credits</th>';
            echo '<th>Faculty</th>';
            echo '<th>Notes</th>';
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr);$i++)
                {
                    if(empty($fac[$i])){
                        $fac[$i]="--";

                    }
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$arr[$i]['subcode'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['subtitle'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['sem'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['credits'].'</td><td>'.$fac[$i].'</td><td> <a download="'.$arr[$i]['subcode'].'.pdf" href="$arr[$i][\'notes\']">'.$arr[$i]['subcode'].' Notes</a></td></tr>';

                }

                echo '</table>';
                echo '<br />';
        ?>




    </div>
```

The link is appearing on the page ,but when i click on it, i am getting "Failed-No file' error.Is the right of specifying the php variable as the source the  tag.
Is there any other this can be done?

[Screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II5rI.png)

Comment: Try showing your html, with the a tag. We would like to see the generated href.

Comment: @PoulBak I'm sorry, i did not understand, do want me to include the entire html file or put the html tags to the code.

Comment: Show the relevant part of your html, including the '<a>' tag.

Comment: @PoulBak Is this fine?. I have also included a screenshot at the end.

Comment: Actually I don't know php, but now people that do can answer.

Comment: I would use a regular href like `download.php`. Check out this link [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: @user409603 inspect download link in devtools. check if the link is working or not by putting it into browser's url bar.

Comment: @Sourav href is not equal to a link but rather a php variable which holds the content of the image that has to be downloaded.

Comment: @user409603 the download requires the link of the file to download. It can't download the contents of the file. just look through download attribute docs.

Comment: @Sourav when  a make href="" and src="$arr[$i]['notes'] " the file is downloaded(it has a size ) ,but when i open it i get a message saying that it is not of the proper format

Comment: @ Sourav Okay, the file that got downloaded was the html page itself and not the intended file

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to download an image from the file content if you know the mime type using the data scheme and base64 encoding.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <?php 

    $mime_type = "image/png";
    $file_content = file_get_contents("img.png");         

    ?>
    <a href="data:<?php echo $mime_type; ?>;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($file_content); ?>" download="anything.png">Download</a>

</body>
```

Comment: i dont want the image to appear on the screen, the download should start once the  link is clicked

Comment: Did you try the code? If the image was displayed that is because of your web browser not supporting the download attribute. I tried this in firefox and it worked.